# Search functions seem to be buggy

Tags: search, entity, admin, shopware, shopware6

Something weird happens when trying to use a custom entity multi-select as a custom field. When searching for "Apple W" these results show:
[image]

Yet when trying to search for "Apple Wat" this happens completely breaking this search functionality:
[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? It also seems to happen in other fields. I've also tried setting the search settings to "AND", but I presume that to only be working for the Storefront search.

**Edit:**

A similar problem seems to appear when using the Storefront search with "OR" as your search behaviour or when having "Split search terms" enabled on 'product name' in the search configuration.

Comment: Would it be possible to hardcode the admin search to "AND" as well? Maybe fixing the problem in the process?